# TypeError while trying to connect to mongoDB using meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a new meteor project, every time I execute `meteor mongo` I get the following:

```
C:\Users\edtho\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:165  
  throw error;                                                                                                                                     
  ^                                                                                                                                                

TypeError: port should be a number or string: null                                                                                                     
    at lookupAndConnect (net.js:942:13)                                                                                                                
    at Socket.connect (net.js:921:5)                                                                                                                   
    at Object.exports.connect.exports.createConnection (net.js:69:35)                                                                                  
    at C:\tools\runners\run-mongo.js:280:24                                                                                                            
    at findMongoPort (C:\tools\runners\run-mongo.js:279:12)                                                                                            
    at Command.func (C:\tools\cli\commands.js:1132:21)                                                                                                 
    at C:\tools\cli\main.js:1410:23
```

I want to clarify that the app wasn't even starting, it was stuck at `starting your app`, I found this solution for that: `set MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/sample` I now have a hunch that this might be what's conflicting?